# ASP.NET MVC Debugging Session not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I've a MCV ASP.NET. It has authentication and authorization.

When ever I run this application in debug mode, the application starts with user already logged in. It doesn't show Logon page.

Could anyone tell me how to fix this issue i.e. clear the session so that it prompts login credentials? I tried clearing cookies etc on IE and issue still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you sure it has forms authentication and not windows authentication? You can check by highlighting project name in solution explorer and press F4. Make sure that anonymous authentication is set to enabled, and Windows Authentication to Disabled.

If you indeed have forms authentication, you can have a link that invokes an action that calls `FormsAuthentication.SignOut();` If you generate a basic "internet application" template, it is generated for you in account controller